# Update model even validations are not satisfied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel

**I want to update my model even validations like `ng-minlength` and `ng-maxlength` is failing.**

I have a scenario to switch tabs which contains similar form with same data. So when I switch it, if the inputs are valid (proper length and pattern) other fields in another form retains the data.

But if input values are invalid, model is not updating hence no retaining of field values.

Is there a way to solve this in AngularJS?
Thanks in advance.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0" ng-app>
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: myForm.mobile.$invalid}">
  <label class="control-label" for="mobile">Mobile</label>
  <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="XXXXXXXXXXX" ng-model="mobile" ng-minlength="11"  required/>
      <span ng-show="myForm.mobile.$error.required" class="help-inline">Required</span>
      <span ng-show="myForm.mobile.$error.minlength" class="help-inline">Mobile number should be minimum 11 character</span>           
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">                       
    <input  class="btn" type="submit" value ="submit" />
  </div>
  <tt>mobile = {{mobile}}</tt><br/>
</div>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMMke/253/)

As you can see in the fiddle mobile is not updating until `min-length` is satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

angular does not apply any change to the **scope** and **$modelValue** if there is any invalid flag set in the model. When you start the validation process, you are setting the **minlength="11"** . That is telling to angular not apply the value to the model unless the value is greater than 10. So, i guess there is no way to update model value unless validation is true..

Comment: to solve this i think the best way is to do validation while submitting data and show error msg at that time...